# I am getting "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." error after upgrading site from wordpress 4.3 to 4.7.3

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I am getting "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." error after upgrading site from wordpress 4.3.x to 4.7.3 and I have upgraded wordpress manually when I upgarded database as per latest wp-admin and wp-includes folder and trying to login using correct credentials it is displying this message.

I have already tried suggetions like changing prefix from my custom prefix to wp_ and disabling and renaming the plugins folder but still getting the same error.

Comment: Check the wp_users table and make you have the correct username. I recently ran into this issue as well, turns out that I had to use the email associated with account to login. See if that works first.

Comment: I have rechecked the username and it is correct. I am able to login but after login to admin I am getting this error. When accessing the login page without admin login i.e I cleared my cookies etc then login screen is working fine.